# TDLib Share phone number with bot

Tags: c#, .net, telegram

How can I send my contact to the bot in chat? The documentation for [`sharePhoneNumber`](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1share_phone_number.html) says that the user must be a mutual contact. But the bot cannot be added to contacts.

I use TDLib 1.8.21. Appropriate method: `TdApi.Client.SharePhoneNumberAsync`

---

Code example:

```
Client = new TdClient();
await Client.SetTdlibParametersAsync(databaseDirectory: DatabaseDir, 
    apiId: apiId, 
    apiHash: apiHash, 
    systemLanguageCode: systemLanguageCode, 
    deviceModel: deviceModel, 
    systemVersion: systemVersion, 
    applicationVersion: version);
await Client.SharePhoneNumberAsync(chatId);
```

Everything works without exceptions, but the contact is not sent. The text message is sent, the contact is not.

Comment: Hello D. Stark, could you provide a working example (see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) of your code to better see what your problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
await Client.SendMessageAsync(chatId, inputMessageContent: new InputMessageContent.InputMessageContact() {
    Contact = new Contact() { PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber }
});
```